# The view or its master was not found

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

```
 <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("123", "PayMonthMore", "Home")
 </li>
```

When I press this button, getting this error.

 My project structure is:
 Controllers
 
    -----HomeController.cs
Views
-----Home
----------Index.cshtml

my method code is:

```
public ActionResult PayMonthMore()
{
    DBModelContainer db = new DBModelContainer();
    var user = db.user.First(u => u.username == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    var paid = user.paidToDate;
    if (paid == null)
    {
        paid = DateTime.Now;
    }
    user.paidToDate = paid.Value.AddMonths(1);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: The error is quite descriptive on its own. So are you sure that you have `PayMonthMore` view? Because your project structure says otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have, probably, I misunderstood @Html.ActionLink usage purpose. I'm pretty new to C#. I wanted to call controller method from webpage to add info to database and that's all. Do I need to use something else?

Comment: If you have the appropriate `PayMonthMore` Home controller method then you do not need anything more.

Comment: `DBModelContainer db = new DBModelContainer();
            var user = db.user.First(u => u.username == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            if (user.paidToDate == null)
            {
                user.paidToDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            user.paidToDate.Value.AddMonths(1);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();` this is my method

Comment: @AndreySaleba Please edit the question and add the code to the main body instead of here as a comment as it is more readable.